# Linq C# Agrupar multiples columnas y mostrar dato con condicion

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo el siguiente método el cual le envió como voy a agrupar los datos de un objeto.

```
  List<Mov> AgruparMovimientos(List<Mov> movimientos, Func<Mov, object> condicion)
    {
        List<Mov> movs = movimientos;

        movs = movs.GroupBy(condicion)
            .Select(g => new Mov()
            {
                Articulo = g.First().Articulo,
                Codigo = g.First().Codigo,
                Familia = g.First().Familia,
                Almacen = g.First().Almacen,
                Fecha = g.OrderByDescending(m => m.Fecha).First().Fecha,
                TipoMov = g.First().TipoMov,
                TipoArticulo = g.First().TipoArticulo,
                Costo = g.Sum(m => m.Costo),
                Cantidad = g.Sum(m => m.Cantidad)
            }).ToList();


        movs.RemoveAll(m => m.Cantidad == 0 && m.Costo == 0);

        return movs;
    }
```

Luego llamo el método de la siguiente forma:

```
movBindingSource.DataSource = AgruparMovimientos(movimientos, m => new { m.Codigo, m.Almacen, m.Familia, m.TipoMov });
```

El tema es el siguiente quisiera poder mostrar por ejemplo cuando agrupe solo por Codigo, que si ese Codigo tiene varias familias muestre "Varias Familias" en vez de:

```
Familia = g.First().Familia
```

intente usando:

```
Familia = g.Count(m => m.Familia) > 1 ? "Varias Familias" : g.First().Familia,
```

pero me da el siguiente error:

> Error CS1662 No se puede convertir expresión lambda en el tipo delegado indicado porque algunos de los tipos de valores devueltos del bloque no se pueden convertir implícitamente en el tipo de valor devuelto del delegado.

**Podrían iluminarme de como poder hacer que si una propiedad no está agrupada y existe varias elementos que se repten poder poner un texto? sin que tenga que escribir un método y un sin número de código?**

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que tu problema está en los tipos de datos, por lo que debes publicar las Clases involucradas.

Comment: Depende del tipo de datos que sea familia, supongo que debe ser un string si usas un mismo objeto

Comment: Puedes usar lo  siguiente en caso de que los dos datos sean string `Familia = String.Join(",", g.ToList().Select(u=>u.Familia).ToList())` La estructura es la siguiente: String.Join(delimitador,lista a unir),  obtenemos la lista de mov que estan agrupados bajo el mismo codigo y selecionamos la lista pero solo con el dato familia